# What happened to unread icons on questions in watched tags?

Tags: support, tags, design, tag-watching

At some point after watched tags were added to Stack Overflow, when looking at the list of questions under my watched tags, there would be a blue circle to the left of any questions that were added since the last time I had looked at my watched tags.

It was this way for at least a year, but in the past month or two the blue circles seem to have completely disappeared. I thought it was a fluke at first, but they haven't returned, and I haven't been able to find an announcement about any changes related to this feature.

Comment: Do you mean your (tag) filter? The ones under the sidebar that says "Custom Filters"?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the issue I'm having, thank you.